# iphone app: put a toolbar on the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, toolbar

I read the iphone UI guide and it notes that toolbar for iphone app is always at the bottom of the page, well if I want to leave the space at the bottom for advertisement, can I put the toolbar on the top?

I know I can use navigationcontrol and UISegmentedControl, but that is designed for navigation. Mine is some buttons (i.e sorting, refresh) working on the current view of a list so that toolbar more suit the purpose.

I figure I can still put toolbar on the top, right? Anyone can share some sample?

thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a toolbar anywhere you want. There's nothing preventing you from doing so. You should use UIToolBar for that. Or just create your own view and put buttons there.